# Ionic: Admob is not defined error and infinite loading on Android app, iOS is fine

Tags: android, ionic-framework, admob, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I put admob into my ionic app. It works fine for ios, but I keep on getting "admob is not defined" error for android and see no ads when I run it on an android phone.

I added and removed the cordova plugin a few times: `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-admobpro`

I also added and removed and readded the android platform from the app, didn't work.

I also added and removed: `cordova plugin add com.google.playservices`, didn't change

The other problem is once I take all the admob stuff out of my code and completely uninstall the plugin, it causes (I am using parse server) parse initialize issues in the same locations as the admob issues in the error below, and the android does infinite loading, the ios app works fine.

Any ideas please? I've been stuck on this for a bit.

[image]

Comment: Plugins does not work in browser. Try android device or emulator with Google Play Services.

Comment: These are the logs from running it on an android device not a browser.

Comment: Which IDE you're using ?

Comment: Check if in plugins folder (in dev tools) there are admob javascript files. You can place a breakpoint there also to see if there is something wrong and fine tune the issue.